# Private files in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've been able to setup my project such that when it uploads images from a given form to AWS S3, the file is set to private.

[image]

Unfortunately, even with this permission set, users can still publicly access these files.

Is there a setting within S3 that I need to set to actually make this 'private' files unaccessible to the public without a signed URL?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the bucket policy associated?

Comment: There is no bucket policy. This may be part of the problem I suppose. Some files in the bucket need to be public while others need to only be accessible by a presigned key. Can this work?

Comment: S3 objects are by default private. You have to make them explicitly public. So how come they are public if you don't have bucket policy?

Comment: I'm assuming it's an IAM policy that has been set

Comment: When you say "users can still publicly access these files", how are they accessing the files? Are they doing it via the S3 management console, or via a URL that points to the file?

Comment: A non-signed URL that points to the file

Comment: If the URL is like `bucketname.s3-region.amazonaws.com/image.jpg`, then the only way that it would be accessible is via `ACL=public-read` or a Bucket Policy that grants access with `s3:GetObject`.

Comment: This is the piece I was missing. thanks!